# Stackoverflow in Treap while using split operation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I'm making a Treap using Java.

```
public class Treap {
    private class Pair<T> {
        private T first;
        private T second;

        public Pair(T first, T second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        public T getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

        public T getSecond() {
            return second;
        }
    }

    private int key;
    private int priority;

    private Treap leftSon;
    private Treap rightSon;

    public Treap(int key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.priority = PriorityGenerator.getPriority();
    }

    public Pair<Treap> split(Treap treap, int key) {
        if (treap == null)
            return new Pair<>(null, null);
        if (key > treap.key) {
            Pair<Treap> pair = split(treap.rightSon, key);
            treap.rightSon = pair.first;
            pair.first = treap;
            return pair;
        }
        else {
            Pair<Treap> pair = split(treap.leftSon, key);
            treap.leftSon = pair.second;
            pair.second = treap;
            return pair;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the split method is sometimes causing the Stackoverflow Exception. But it sometimes works correctly. I don't really understand where's the problem. Can someone help me fix that?

Comment: I don't see where you defined the `insert` method. However, a `StackOverflowError` occurs when your stack (nested method calls) is too high, that's a liability with using recursive algorithms.

Comment: insert method is using split, sorry, typed the insert instead of splt
yeah, I know that, the problem is that it sometimes works correctly and sometimes not

Comment: What is the size of the `Treap` you wanted to split that ended up causing a `SOE` ? This error is typically caused by too many recursive calls. As the limit is somewhat pretty big, it's often caused by flaws in the design rather than actually needing to reach the actual limit. I don't see your code going in an infinite loop except if one of the children Treap possess one of its ancestor as a child.

Comment: Please, add all the relevant code to reproduce the problem to the question.